# Laravel 5.2 redirect doesn't save flash messages

Tags: laravel

I installed fresh laravel 5.2.29.
My routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/a', function () {
        return redirect('/b', 302)->with('error', 'error description');
    });

    Route::get('/b', function () {
        return session('error');
    });
});
```

When I go to `/a` in browser it redirects me to `/b`, but shows me nothing. What should I do to it show me `error description`? Or why does not it store flash data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, if you are running Laravel 5.2.27 and up, do not use the web middleware group. It is applied for you by default as you can see in `app/Http/RouteServiceProvider.php`:

```
protected function mapWebRoutes(Router $router)
{
    $router->group([
        'namespace' => $this->namespace, 'middleware' => 'web',
    ], function ($router) {
        require app_path('Http/routes.php');
    });
}
```

If you try to apply the web middleware again, you'll run into weird problems like what you are currently facing.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But it is strange, in my second project all routes use `web` middleware and all work normally. The version of second project is 5.2.29 too.

Comment: @melihovv If you updated to 5.2.29 from an older version, it won't affect you because only your `vendor` directory is updated. This only affects fresh new installations of Laravel. In other words, if you run composer update, the `app` directory will never be modified, and the latest `RouteServiceProvider` lies in the `app` directory.